# How to monitor all CircuitBreakers in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to monitor all `Circuit Breakers` limits and size?

`Fielddata Breaker` can be monitored using this by node:

```
GET _nodes/stats/breaker,http
```

But how can we monitor the other Breakers like `breaker.request` and `breaker.total` ?

ElasticSearch-version: 1.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those breakers are available from 1.4.x on. See [this](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/6739) PR in github with details that seem to indicate this.

And I've tested shortly this and I can see the additional requests breaker:

```
 "breakers": {
    "request": {
       "limit_size_in_bytes": 415550668,
       "limit_size": "396.2mb",
       "estimated_size_in_bytes": 0,
       "estimated_size": "0b",
       "overhead": 1,
       "tripped": 0
    },
    "fielddata": {
       "limit_size_in_bytes": 623326003,
       "limit_size": "594.4mb",
       "estimated_size_in_bytes": 2847496,
       "estimated_size": "2.7mb",
       "overhead": 1.03,
       "tripped": 0
    },
    "parent": {
       "limit_size_in_bytes": 727213670,
       "limit_size": "693.5mb",
       "estimated_size_in_bytes": 2847496,
       "estimated_size": "2.7mb",
       "overhead": 1,
       "tripped": 0
    }
 }
```